# Python numpy multidimensional array indexing

Tags: python

I have a problem trying to indexing elements in numpy array

```
import numpy as np

a=np.zeros([10,6,1,1],dtype=np.float32)
```

And I want to do something like that,
e.g. `print(a[2,3,1,1])`

but it gives wrong indexing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indexes are zero-based.

If you create an array of size 10, you index the elements as 0-9

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> a=np.zeros([10,6,1,1],dtype=np.float32)
>>> print a[1, 2, 0, 0]
0.0
```